# How to insert data into a MySQL database table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a table in my database but the data including users id/account is not recorded into the table. I've got this problem during the creating a sign up & login page via php:

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email) VALUE      ('Peter', 'Parker', 'peterparker@mail.com')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please, try to be more clear and add code or examples. Sincerely, I don't understand your question or problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `VALUES` not `VALUE`

Your statment should be

```
INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES    ('Peter', 'Parker', 'peterparker@mail.com')
```